# Retornar objetos de un for con estilos aplicado en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, bucle-for

estoy iniciando en javascript y tengo un array de objetos, y quisiera retornarlos uno por uno para que aparecieran estilizados.

El problema es que solo me retorna el ultimo objeto del array con los estilos aplicados; y no cada uno de los objetos existentes.

Hoja de estilos a aplicar: .wapper lo utilizo para así poder obtener dos columnas automáticas.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  float:left;
  width:80%;
  padding:0 20px;
  background: #E8E5DA;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-top:30px;
  font: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 22px;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #D62828;
  font: 120% sans-serif;
}
```

En mi .html es donde tengo mi script a ejecutar
El error se encuentra básicamente en la manera en la cual retorno mis valores.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Platillo(nombre,precio,tipo) {
          this.nombre = nombre;
          this.precio = precio;
          this.tipo = tipo;
        }

        var platillos = [];
        var p1 = new Platillo("Hongos Portobello",115,"Aperitivo");
        var p2 = new Platillo("Pasta Gamberi",130,"Aperitivo");
        var p3 = new Platillo("Trío de Bruschetas Serrano",115,"Aperitivo");
        var p4 = new Platillo("Milanesa de Pollo",85,"Carne");
        var p5 = new Platillo("Filete de Pescado",115,"Pescado");
        var p6 = new Platillo("Pollo al limón",210,"Carne");
        var p7 = new Platillo("Chicarron de rib eye",295,"Carne");
        var p8= new Platillo("Pastel de Chocolate",60,"Postre");
        var p9 = new Platillo("Flan Napolitano",665,"Postre");
        var p10 = new Platillo("Fondant Choco",115,"Postre");
        platillos.push(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10);


        function mostrarListado(){
          var lista='';
          for(var i=0; i<platillos.length; i++){
            document.getElementById('nombreProducto').innerText = platillos[i].nombre;
            document.getElementById('precioProducto').innerText =  'Precio de venta: ' + '$' + platillos[i].precio + 'MXN';
            document.getElementById('tipoComida').innerText =  'Tipo de comida: ' + platillos[i].tipo;
          }

        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="mostrarListado()">
        <main>
          <section>
            <h1>Menú</h1>
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div>
                <h2 id = "nombreProducto"></h2>
                <ul>
                  <li id = "precioProducto"></li>
                  <li id = "tipoComida"></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>

          </section>
        </main>
```

Sé que una manera de retornar todo correctamente seria recorrer el arreglo con un for y guardar en una cadena todo formateado y así retornarlo en un div; pero necesito aplicar los estilos y de esa manera no me sería posible.

Obtengo esto:
[image: Error obtenido:]

Y necesito obtener esto:
[image: Forma correcta]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sale el último elemento porque se está sobrescribiendo el contenido de los elementos `nombreProducto, precioProducto, tipoComida` en cada iteración del bucle.

Lo que necesitas hacer es generar el siguiente bloque de `html` para cada platillo e insertarlo de una vez en el `wrapper`. El navegador es capaz de interpretar el `html` de la cadena texto y crear los elementos en el [DOM](http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/dom/).

```html
 <div>
   <h2 id="nombreProducto"></h2>
   <ul>
     <li id="precioProducto"></li>
     <li id="tipoComida"></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Los estilos no se pierden porque estas usando el selector del elemento `h2` que se aplicará a todos los elementos `h2` que haya en la página. A menos que se sobreescriba en otro sitio en tu hoja de estilos o por javascript.

```js
 function Platillo(nombre, precio, tipo) {
   this.nombre = nombre;
   this.precio = precio;
   this.tipo = tipo;
 }

 var platillos = [];
 var p1 = new Platillo("Hongos Portobello", 115, "Aperitivo");
 var p2 = new Platillo("Pasta Gamberi", 130, "Aperitivo");
 var p3 = new Platillo("Trío de Bruschetas Serrano", 115, "Aperitivo");
 var p4 = new Platillo("Milanesa de Pollo", 85, "Carne");
 var p5 = new Platillo("Filete de Pescado", 115, "Pescado");
 var p6 = new Platillo("Pollo al limón", 210, "Carne");
 var p7 = new Platillo("Chicarron de rib eye", 295, "Carne");
 var p8 = new Platillo("Pastel de Chocolate", 60, "Postre");
 var p9 = new Platillo("Flan Napolitano", 665, "Postre");
 var p10 = new Platillo("Fondant Choco", 115, "Postre");
 platillos.push(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10);


 function mostrarListado() {
   var listado = '';
  // tal como puedes ver se itera los platillos
  // y se va creando un cadena de texto con el html resultante por cada iteración

   for (var i = 0; i < platillos.length; i++) {
    // el operador "+=" significa añade el siguiente valor al valor que ya hay en la variable listado. 
     listado += `<div>
                  <h2>${platillos[i].nombre}</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Precio de venta: ${platillos[i].precio}</li>
                    <li>Tipo de comida: ${platillos[i].tipo}</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>`;
   }
  // des comenta la siguiente linea para ver el html que se generado
  // console.log(listado);
   // luego de generar el html necesario se inserta en el elemento padre, que es el wrapper
   document.querySelector('.wrapper').innerHTML = listado;
 }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  float:left;
  width:80%;
  padding:0 20px;
  background: #E8E5DA;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-top:30px;
  font: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 22px;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #D62828;
  font: 120% sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body onload="mostrarListado()">
<main>
   <section>
     <h1>Menú</h1>
     <div class="wrapper"><!-- Aquí se insertará el contenido --></div>
   </section>
 </main>
 </body>
```

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Answer (score 0):

1.- Ya casi tienes todo resuelto, lo que yo te recomendaría es que a tu div con la clase **wrapper** le vayas añadiendo los elementos, por lo que tu html quedaria asi:

```
 <main>
      <section>
        <h1>Menú</h1>
        <div class="wrapper">

        </div>
      </section>
  </main>
```

2.- Lo mas recomendable es que tu objeto **platillos** lo recorras con `foreach`

```
platillos.forEach((platillo) => {}
```

3.- Por cada elemento recorrido traeras un platillo y ahi creas un **template literal** con la informacion de cada platillo recorrido

```
platillos.forEach((platillo) => {
    wrapper.innerHTML += `<div>
                <h2 id = "nombreProducto">${platillo.nombre}</h2>
                <ul>
                  <li id = "precioProducto">
                  Precio de venta:  $platillo.precio MXN
                  </li>
                  <li id = "tipoComida">
                  Tipo de comida: platillo.tipo
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>`;
  });
```

4.- Te muestro un ejemplo con codigo para que puedas entenderlo mejor

```js
function Platillo(nombre, precio, tipo) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.precio = precio;
  this.tipo = tipo;
}

var platillos = [];
var p1 = new Platillo("Hongos Portobello", 115, "Aperitivo");
var p2 = new Platillo("Pasta Gamberi", 130, "Aperitivo");
var p3 = new Platillo("Trío de Bruschetas Serrano", 115, "Aperitivo");
var p4 = new Platillo("Milanesa de Pollo", 85, "Carne");
var p5 = new Platillo("Filete de Pescado", 115, "Pescado");
var p6 = new Platillo("Pollo al limón", 210, "Carne");
var p7 = new Platillo("Chicarron de rib eye", 295, "Carne");
var p8 = new Platillo("Pastel de Chocolate", 60, "Postre");
var p9 = new Platillo("Flan Napolitano", 665, "Postre");
var p10 = new Platillo("Fondant Choco", 115, "Postre");
platillos.push(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10);

function mostrarListado() {
  //elemento wrapper
  let wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

  platillos.forEach((platillo) => {
  //NOTA EL += esto hara que se vayan añaniendo los platillos
    wrapper.innerHTML += `<div>
                <h2 id = "nombreProducto">${platillo.nombre}</h2>
                <ul>
                  <li id = "precioProducto">
                  Precio de venta:  ${platillo.precio} MXN
                  </li>
                  <li id = "tipoComida">
                  Tipo de comida: ${platillo.tipo}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>`;
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  float:left;
  width:80%;
  padding:0 20px;
  background: #E8E5DA;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-top:30px;
  font: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 22px;
}

h2 {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  color: #D62828;
  font: 120% sans-serif;
}
```

```html
 <body onload="mostrarListado()">
    <main>
      <section>
        <h1>Menú</h1>
        <div class="wrapper"></div>
      </section>
    </main>

  </body>
```

Comment: ¿En qué se diferencia tu aporte de la otra respuesta?

Comment: @BetaM No me di cuenta que ya habian respondido cuando publique la respuesta ya estaba la respuesta del otro usuario, Aunque si buscamos diferencias pues la unica es la manera de recorrer el objeto. Saludos.